# Calculate onset of rainfall season with conditions

Tags: python, datetime

I want to implement this rule to get the start of the rainfall season of each year in dataset (according to Sivakumar): The start of the rainfall season corresponds to a *date X* on which an amount of 20mm of rain will have been collected in 3 consecutive days after May 1st without rain of more than 7 days.

So, there should be 3 conditions:

1. *X* is after the 1st May
2. the total rain in the next 3 days after *X* should be >= 20 mm
3. there should be rain between the 4th and the 10th day after *X*

Here is a year of rainfall data in form of a dictionary. Convert it into dataframe to try out your code.

```
{'Date': {0: Timestamp('1931-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('1931-01-02 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('1931-01-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('1931-01-04 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('1931-01-05 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('1931-01-06 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('1931-01-07 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('1931-01-08 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('1931-01-09 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('1931-01-10 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('1931-01-11 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('1931-01-12 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('1931-01-13 00:00:00'),
  13: Timestamp('1931-01-14 00:00:00'),
  14: Timestamp('1931-01-15 00:00:00'),
  15: Timestamp('1931-01-16 00:00:00'),
  16: Timestamp('1931-01-17 00:00:00'),
  17: Timestamp('1931-01-18 00:00:00'),
  18: Timestamp('1931-01-19 00:00:00'),
  19: Timestamp('1931-01-20 00:00:00'),
  20: Timestamp('1931-01-21 00:00:00'),
  21: Timestamp('1931-01-22 00:00:00'),
  22: Timestamp('1931-01-23 00:00:00'),
  23: Timestamp('1931-01-24 00:00:00'),
  24: Timestamp('1931-01-25 00:00:00'),
  25: Timestamp('1931-01-26 00:00:00'),
  26: Timestamp('1931-01-27 00:00:00'),
  27: Timestamp('1931-01-28 00:00:00'),
  28: Timestamp('1931-01-29 00:00:00'),
  29: Timestamp('1931-01-30 00:00:00'),
  30: Timestamp('1931-01-31 00:00:00'),
  31: Timestamp('1931-02-01 00:00:00'),
  32: Timestamp('1931-02-02 00:00:00'),
  33: Timestamp('1931-02-03 00:00:00'),
  34: Timestamp('1931-02-04 00:00:00'),
  35: Timestamp('1931-02-05 00:00:00'),
  36: Timestamp('1931-02-06 00:00:00'),
  37: Timestamp('1931-02-07 00:00:00'),
  38: Timestamp('1931-02-08 00:00:00'),
  39: Timestamp('1931-02-09 00:00:00'),
  40: Timestamp('1931-02-10 00:00:00'),
  41: Timestamp('1931-02-11 00:00:00'),
  42: Timestamp('1931-02-12 00:00:00'),
  43: Timestamp('1931-02-13 00:00:00'),
  44: Timestamp('1931-02-14 00:00:00'),
  45: Timestamp('1931-02-15 00:00:00'),
  46: Timestamp('1931-02-16 00:00:00'),
  47: Timestamp('1931-02-17 00:00:00'),
  48: Timestamp('1931-02-18 00:00:00'),
  49: Timestamp('1931-02-19 00:00:00'),
  50: Timestamp('1931-02-20 00:00:00'),
  51: Timestamp('1931-02-21 00:00:00'),
  52: Timestamp('1931-02-22 00:00:00'),
  53: Timestamp('1931-02-23 00:00:00'),
  54: Timestamp('1931-02-24 00:00:00'),
  55: Timestamp('1931-02-25 00:00:00'),
  56: Timestamp('1931-02-26 00:00:00'),
  57: Timestamp('1931-02-27 00:00:00'),
  58: Timestamp('1931-02-28 00:00:00'),
  59: Timestamp('1931-03-01 00:00:00'),
  60: Timestamp('1931-03-02 00:00:00'),
  61: Timestamp('1931-03-03 00:00:00'),
  62: Timestamp('1931-03-04 00:00:00'),
  63: Timestamp('1931-03-05 00:00:00'),
  64: Timestamp('1931-03-06 00:00:00'),
  65: Timestamp('1931-03-07 00:00:00'),
  66: Timestamp('1931-03-08 00:00:00'),
  67: Timestamp('1931-03-09 00:00:00'),
  68: Timestamp('1931-03-10 00:00:00'),
  69: Timestamp('1931-03-11 00:00:00'),
  70: Timestamp('1931-03-12 00:00:00'),
  71: Timestamp('1931-03-13 00:00:00'),
  72: Timestamp('1931-03-14 00:00:00'),
  73: Timestamp('1931-03-15 00:00:00'),
  74: Timestamp('1931-03-16 00:00:00'),
  75: Timestamp('1931-03-17 00:00:00'),
  76: Timestamp('1931-03-18 00:00:00'),
  77: Timestamp('1931-03-19 00:00:00'),
  78: Timestamp('1931-03-20 00:00:00'),
  79: Timestamp('1931-03-21 00:00:00'),
  80: Timestamp('1931-03-22 00:00:00'),
  81: Timestamp('1931-03-23 00:00:00'),
  82: Timestamp('1931-03-24 00:00:00'),
  83: Timestamp('1931-03-25 00:00:00'),
  84: Timestamp('1931-03-26 00:00:00'),
  85: Timestamp('1931-03-27 00:00:00'),
  86: Timestamp('1931-03-28 00:00:00'),
  87: Timestamp('1931-03-29 00:00:00'),
  88: Timestamp('1931-03-30 00:00:00'),
  89: Timestamp('1931-03-31 00:00:00'),
  90: Timestamp('1931-04-01 00:00:00'),
  91: Timestamp('1931-04-02 00:00:00'),
  92: Timestamp('1931-04-03 00:00:00'),
  93: Timestamp('1931-04-04 00:00:00'),
  94: Timestamp('1931-04-05 00:00:00'),
  95: Timestamp('1931-04-06 00:00:00'),
  96: Timestamp('1931-04-07 00:00:00'),
  97: Timestamp('1931-04-08 00:00:00'),
  98: Timestamp('1931-04-09 00:00:00'),
  99: Timestamp('1931-04-10 00:00:00'),
  100: Timestamp('1931-04-11 00:00:00'),
  101: Timestamp('1931-04-12 00:00:00'),
  102: Timestamp('1931-04-13 00:00:00'),
  103: Timestamp('1931-04-14 00:00:00'),
  104: Timestamp('1931-04-15 00:00:00'),
  105: Timestamp('1931-04-16 00:00:00'),
  106: Timestamp('1931-04-17 00:00:00'),
  107: Timestamp('1931-04-18 00:00:00'),
  108: Timestamp('1931-04-19 00:00:00'),
  109: Timestamp('1931-04-20 00:00:00'),
  110: Timestamp('1931-04-21 00:00:00'),
  111: Timestamp('1931-04-22 00:00:00'),
  112: Timestamp('1931-04-23 00:00:00'),
  113: Timestamp('1931-04-24 00:00:00'),
  114: Timestamp('1931-04-25 00:00:00'),
  115: Timestamp('1931-04-26 00:00:00'),
  116: Timestamp('1931-04-27 00:00:00'),
  117: Timestamp('1931-04-28 00:00:00'),
  118: Timestamp('1931-04-29 00:00:00'),
  119: Timestamp('1931-04-30 00:00:00'),
  120: Timestamp('1931-05-01 00:00:00'),
  121: Timestamp('1931-05-02 00:00:00'),
  122: Timestamp('1931-05-03 00:00:00'),
  123: Timestamp('1931-05-04 00:00:00'),
  124: Timestamp('1931-05-05 00:00:00'),
  125: Timestamp('1931-05-06 00:00:00'),
  126: Timestamp('1931-05-07 00:00:00'),
  127: Timestamp('1931-05-08 00:00:00'),
  128: Timestamp('1931-05-09 00:00:00'),
  129: Timestamp('1931-05-10 00:00:00'),
  130: Timestamp('1931-05-11 00:00:00'),
  131: Timestamp('1931-05-12 00:00:00'),
  132: Timestamp('1931-05-13 00:00:00'),
  133: Timestamp('1931-05-14 00:00:00'),
  134: Timestamp('1931-05-15 00:00:00'),
  135: Timestamp('1931-05-16 00:00:00'),
  136: Timestamp('1931-05-17 00:00:00'),
  137: Timestamp('1931-05-18 00:00:00'),
  138: Timestamp('1931-05-19 00:00:00'),
  139: Timestamp('1931-05-20 00:00:00'),
  140: Timestamp('1931-05-21 00:00:00'),
  141: Timestamp('1931-05-22 00:00:00'),
  142: Timestamp('1931-05-23 00:00:00'),
  143: Timestamp('1931-05-24 00:00:00'),
  144: Timestamp('1931-05-25 00:00:00'),
  145: Timestamp('1931-05-26 00:00:00'),
  146: Timestamp('1931-05-27 00:00:00'),
  147: Timestamp('1931-05-28 00:00:00'),
  148: Timestamp('1931-05-29 00:00:00'),
  149: Timestamp('1931-05-30 00:00:00'),
  150: Timestamp('1931-05-31 00:00:00'),
  151: Timestamp('1931-06-01 00:00:00'),
  152: Timestamp('1931-06-02 00:00:00'),
  153: Timestamp('1931-06-03 00:00:00'),
  154: Timestamp('1931-06-04 00:00:00'),
  155: Timestamp('1931-06-05 00:00:00'),
  156: Timestamp('1931-06-06 00:00:00'),
  157: Timestamp('1931-06-07 00:00:00'),
  158: Timestamp('1931-06-08 00:00:00'),
  159: Timestamp('1931-06-09 00:00:00'),
  160: Timestamp('1931-06-10 00:00:00'),
  161: Timestamp('1931-06-11 00:00:00'),
  162: Timestamp('1931-06-12 00:00:00'),
  163: Timestamp('1931-06-13 00:00:00'),
  164: Timestamp('1931-06-14 00:00:00'),
  165: Timestamp('1931-06-15 00:00:00'),
  166: Timestamp('1931-06-16 00:00:00'),
  167: Timestamp('1931-06-17 00:00:00'),
  168: Timestamp('1931-06-18 00:00:00'),
  169: Timestamp('1931-06-19 00:00:00'),
  170: Timestamp('1931-06-20 00:00:00'),
  171: Timestamp('1931-06-21 00:00:00'),
  172: Timestamp('1931-06-22 00:00:00'),
  173: Timestamp('1931-06-23 00:00:00'),
  174: Timestamp('1931-06-24 00:00:00'),
  175: Timestamp('1931-06-25 00:00:00'),
  176: Timestamp('1931-06-26 00:00:00'),
  177: Timestamp('1931-06-27 00:00:00'),
  178: Timestamp('1931-06-28 00:00:00'),
  179: Timestamp('1931-06-29 00:00:00'),
  180: Timestamp('1931-06-30 00:00:00'),
  181: Timestamp('1931-07-01 00:00:00'),
  182: Timestamp('1931-07-02 00:00:00'),
  183: Timestamp('1931-07-03 00:00:00'),
  184: Timestamp('1931-07-04 00:00:00'),
  185: Timestamp('1931-07-05 00:00:00'),
  186: Timestamp('1931-07-06 00:00:00'),
  187: Timestamp('1931-07-07 00:00:00'),
  188: Timestamp('1931-07-08 00:00:00'),
  189: Timestamp('1931-07-09 00:00:00'),
  190: Timestamp('1931-07-10 00:00:00'),
  191: Timestamp('1931-07-11 00:00:00'),
  192: Timestamp('1931-07-12 00:00:00'),
  193: Timestamp('1931-07-13 00:00:00'),
  194: Timestamp('1931-07-14 00:00:00'),
  195: Timestamp('1931-07-15 00:00:00'),
  196: Timestamp('1931-07-16 00:00:00'),
  197: Timestamp('1931-07-17 00:00:00'),
  198: Timestamp('1931-07-18 00:00:00'),
  199: Timestamp('1931-07-19 00:00:00'),
  200: Timestamp('1931-07-20 00:00:00'),
  201: Timestamp('1931-07-21 00:00:00'),
  202: Timestamp('1931-07-22 00:00:00'),
  203: Timestamp('1931-07-23 00:00:00'),
  204: Timestamp('1931-07-24 00:00:00'),
  205: Timestamp('1931-07-25 00:00:00'),
  206: Timestamp('1931-07-26 00:00:00'),
  207: Timestamp('1931-07-27 00:00:00'),
  208: Timestamp('1931-07-28 00:00:00'),
  209: Timestamp('1931-07-29 00:00:00'),
  210: Timestamp('1931-07-30 00:00:00'),
  211: Timestamp('1931-07-31 00:00:00'),
  212: Timestamp('1931-08-01 00:00:00'),
  213: Timestamp('1931-08-02 00:00:00'),
  214: Timestamp('1931-08-03 00:00:00'),
  215: Timestamp('1931-08-04 00:00:00'),
  216: Timestamp('1931-08-05 00:00:00'),
  217: Timestamp('1931-08-06 00:00:00'),
  218: Timestamp('1931-08-07 00:00:00'),
  219: Timestamp('1931-08-08 00:00:00'),
  220: Timestamp('1931-08-09 00:00:00'),
  221: Timestamp('1931-08-10 00:00:00'),
  222: Timestamp('1931-08-11 00:00:00'),
  223: Timestamp('1931-08-12 00:00:00'),
  224: Timestamp('1931-08-13 00:00:00'),
  225: Timestamp('1931-08-14 00:00:00'),
  226: Timestamp('1931-08-15 00:00:00'),
  227: Timestamp('1931-08-16 00:00:00'),
  228: Timestamp('1931-08-17 00:00:00'),
  229: Timestamp('1931-08-18 00:00:00'),
  230: Timestamp('1931-08-19 00:00:00'),
  231: Timestamp('1931-08-20 00:00:00'),
  232: Timestamp('1931-08-21 00:00:00'),
  233: Timestamp('1931-08-22 00:00:00'),
  234: Timestamp('1931-08-23 00:00:00'),
  235: Timestamp('1931-08-24 00:00:00'),
  236: Timestamp('1931-08-25 00:00:00'),
  237: Timestamp('1931-08-26 00:00:00'),
  238: Timestamp('1931-08-27 00:00:00'),
  239: Timestamp('1931-08-28 00:00:00'),
  240: Timestamp('1931-08-29 00:00:00'),
  241: Timestamp('1931-08-30 00:00:00'),
  242: Timestamp('1931-08-31 00:00:00'),
  243: Timestamp('1931-09-01 00:00:00'),
  244: Timestamp('1931-09-02 00:00:00'),
  245: Timestamp('1931-09-03 00:00:00'),
  246: Timestamp('1931-09-04 00:00:00'),
  247: Timestamp('1931-09-05 00:00:00'),
  248: Timestamp('1931-09-06 00:00:00'),
  249: Timestamp('1931-09-07 00:00:00'),
  250: Timestamp('1931-09-08 00:00:00'),
  251: Timestamp('1931-09-09 00:00:00'),
  252: Timestamp('1931-09-10 00:00:00'),
  253: Timestamp('1931-09-11 00:00:00'),
  254: Timestamp('1931-09-12 00:00:00'),
  255: Timestamp('1931-09-13 00:00:00'),
  256: Timestamp('1931-09-14 00:00:00'),
  257: Timestamp('1931-09-15 00:00:00'),
  258: Timestamp('1931-09-16 00:00:00'),
  259: Timestamp('1931-09-17 00:00:00'),
  260: Timestamp('1931-09-18 00:00:00'),
  261: Timestamp('1931-09-19 00:00:00'),
  262: Timestamp('1931-09-20 00:00:00'),
  263: Timestamp('1931-09-21 00:00:00'),
  264: Timestamp('1931-09-22 00:00:00'),
  265: Timestamp('1931-09-23 00:00:00'),
  266: Timestamp('1931-09-24 00:00:00'),
  267: Timestamp('1931-09-25 00:00:00'),
  268: Timestamp('1931-09-26 00:00:00'),
  269: Timestamp('1931-09-27 00:00:00'),
  270: Timestamp('1931-09-28 00:00:00'),
  271: Timestamp('1931-09-29 00:00:00'),
  272: Timestamp('1931-09-30 00:00:00'),
  273: Timestamp('1931-10-01 00:00:00'),
  274: Timestamp('1931-10-02 00:00:00'),
  275: Timestamp('1931-10-03 00:00:00'),
  276: Timestamp('1931-10-04 00:00:00'),
  277: Timestamp('1931-10-05 00:00:00'),
  278: Timestamp('1931-10-06 00:00:00'),
  279: Timestamp('1931-10-07 00:00:00'),
  280: Timestamp('1931-10-08 00:00:00'),
  281: Timestamp('1931-10-09 00:00:00'),
  282: Timestamp('1931-10-10 00:00:00'),
  283: Timestamp('1931-10-11 00:00:00'),
  284: Timestamp('1931-10-12 00:00:00'),
  285: Timestamp('1931-10-13 00:00:00'),
  286: Timestamp('1931-10-14 00:00:00'),
  287: Timestamp('1931-10-15 00:00:00'),
  288: Timestamp('1931-10-16 00:00:00'),
  289: Timestamp('1931-10-17 00:00:00'),
  290: Timestamp('1931-10-18 00:00:00'),
  291: Timestamp('1931-10-19 00:00:00'),
  292: Timestamp('1931-10-20 00:00:00'),
  293: Timestamp('1931-10-21 00:00:00'),
  294: Timestamp('1931-10-22 00:00:00'),
  295: Timestamp('1931-10-23 00:00:00'),
  296: Timestamp('1931-10-24 00:00:00'),
  297: Timestamp('1931-10-25 00:00:00'),
  298: Timestamp('1931-10-26 00:00:00'),
  299: Timestamp('1931-10-27 00:00:00'),
  300: Timestamp('1931-10-28 00:00:00'),
  301: Timestamp('1931-10-29 00:00:00'),
  302: Timestamp('1931-10-30 00:00:00'),
  303: Timestamp('1931-10-31 00:00:00'),
  304: Timestamp('1931-11-01 00:00:00'),
  305: Timestamp('1931-11-02 00:00:00'),
  306: Timestamp('1931-11-03 00:00:00'),
  307: Timestamp('1931-11-04 00:00:00'),
  308: Timestamp('1931-11-05 00:00:00'),
  309: Timestamp('1931-11-06 00:00:00'),
  310: Timestamp('1931-11-07 00:00:00'),
  311: Timestamp('1931-11-08 00:00:00'),
  312: Timestamp('1931-11-09 00:00:00'),
  313: Timestamp('1931-11-10 00:00:00'),
  314: Timestamp('1931-11-11 00:00:00'),
  315: Timestamp('1931-11-12 00:00:00'),
  316: Timestamp('1931-11-13 00:00:00'),
  317: Timestamp('1931-11-14 00:00:00'),
  318: Timestamp('1931-11-15 00:00:00'),
  319: Timestamp('1931-11-16 00:00:00'),
  320: Timestamp('1931-11-17 00:00:00'),
  321: Timestamp('1931-11-18 00:00:00'),
  322: Timestamp('1931-11-19 00:00:00'),
  323: Timestamp('1931-11-20 00:00:00'),
  324: Timestamp('1931-11-21 00:00:00'),
  325: Timestamp('1931-11-22 00:00:00'),
  326: Timestamp('1931-11-23 00:00:00'),
  327: Timestamp('1931-11-24 00:00:00'),
  328: Timestamp('1931-11-25 00:00:00'),
  329: Timestamp('1931-11-26 00:00:00'),
  330: Timestamp('1931-11-27 00:00:00'),
  331: Timestamp('1931-11-28 00:00:00'),
  332: Timestamp('1931-11-29 00:00:00'),
  333: Timestamp('1931-11-30 00:00:00'),
  334: Timestamp('1931-12-01 00:00:00'),
  335: Timestamp('1931-12-02 00:00:00'),
  336: Timestamp('1931-12-03 00:00:00'),
  337: Timestamp('1931-12-04 00:00:00'),
  338: Timestamp('1931-12-05 00:00:00'),
  339: Timestamp('1931-12-06 00:00:00'),
  340: Timestamp('1931-12-07 00:00:00'),
  341: Timestamp('1931-12-08 00:00:00'),
  342: Timestamp('1931-12-09 00:00:00'),
  343: Timestamp('1931-12-10 00:00:00'),
  344: Timestamp('1931-12-11 00:00:00'),
  345: Timestamp('1931-12-12 00:00:00'),
  346: Timestamp('1931-12-13 00:00:00'),
  347: Timestamp('1931-12-14 00:00:00'),
  348: Timestamp('1931-12-15 00:00:00'),
  349: Timestamp('1931-12-16 00:00:00'),
  350: Timestamp('1931-12-17 00:00:00'),
  351: Timestamp('1931-12-18 00:00:00'),
  352: Timestamp('1931-12-19 00:00:00'),
  353: Timestamp('1931-12-20 00:00:00'),
  354: Timestamp('1931-12-21 00:00:00'),
  355: Timestamp('1931-12-22 00:00:00'),
  356: Timestamp('1931-12-23 00:00:00'),
  357: Timestamp('1931-12-24 00:00:00'),
  358: Timestamp('1931-12-25 00:00:00'),
  359: Timestamp('1931-12-26 00:00:00'),
  360: Timestamp('1931-12-27 00:00:00'),
  361: Timestamp('1931-12-28 00:00:00'),
  362: Timestamp('1931-12-29 00:00:00'),
  363: Timestamp('1931-12-30 00:00:00'),
  364: Timestamp('1931-12-31 00:00:00')},
 'Rain': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0,
  20: 0.0,
  21: 0.0,
  22: 0.0,
  23: 0.0,
  24: 0.0,
  25: 0.0,
  26: 0.0,
  27: 0.0,
  28: 0.0,
  29: 0.0,
  30: 0.0,
  31: 0.0,
  32: 0.0,
  33: 0.0,
  34: 0.0,
  35: 0.0,
  36: 0.0,
  37: 0.0,
  38: 0.0,
  39: 0.0,
  40: 0.0,
  41: 0.0,
  42: 0.0,
  43: 0.0,
  44: 0.0,
  45: 0.0,
  46: 0.0,
  47: 0.0,
  48: 0.0,
  49: 0.0,
  50: 0.0,
  51: 0.0,
  52: 0.0,
  53: 0.0,
  54: 0.0,
  55: 0.0,
  56: 0.0,
  57: 0.0,
  58: 0.0,
  59: 0.0,
  60: 0.0,
  61: 0.0,
  62: 0.0,
  63: 0.0,
  64: 0.0,
  65: 0.0,
  66: 0.0,
  67: 0.0,
  68: 0.0,
  69: 0.0,
  70: 0.0,
  71: 0.0,
  72: 0.0,
  73: 0.0,
  74: 0.0,
  75: 0.0,
  76: 0.0,
  77: 0.0,
  78: 0.0,
  79: 0.0,
  80: 0.0,
  81: 0.0,
  82: 0.0,
  83: 0.0,
  84: 0.0,
  85: 0.0,
  86: 0.0,
  87: 0.0,
  88: 0.0,
  89: 0.0,
  90: 0.0,
  91: 0.0,
  92: 0.0,
  93: 0.0,
  94: 0.0,
  95: 0.0,
  96: 0.0,
  97: 0.0,
  98: 0.0,
  99: 0.0,
  100: 0.0,
  101: 0.0,
  102: 0.0,
  103: 0.0,
  104: 0.0,
  105: 0.0,
  106: 0.0,
  107: 0.0,
  108: 0.0,
  109: 0.0,
  110: 0.0,
  111: 0.0,
  112: 0.0,
  113: 0.0,
  114: 0.0,
  115: 12.0,
  116: 0.0,
  117: 0.0,
  118: 0.0,
  119: 0.0,
  120: 0.0,
  121: 0.0,
  122: 0.0,
  123: 0.0,
  124: 0.0,
  125: 0.0,
  126: 0.0,
  127: 0.0,
  128: 0.0,
  129: 0.0,
  130: 0.0,
  131: 0.0,
  132: 0.0,
  133: 0.0,
  134: 0.0,
  135: 0.0,
  136: 11.4,
  137: 0.0,
  138: 0.0,
  139: 0.0,
  140: 6.9,
  141: 0.0,
  142: 23.4,
  143: 0.0,
  144: 0.0,
  145: 0.0,
  146: 0.0,
  147: 0.0,
  148: 0.0,
  149: 0.0,
  150: 0.0,
  151: 0.0,
  152: 0.0,
  153: 0.0,
  154: 0.0,
  155: 0.0,
  156: 0.0,
  157: 0.0,
  158: 0.0,
  159: 0.0,
  160: 0.0,
  161: 7.7,
  162: 26.2,
  163: 0.0,
  164: 63.5,
  165: 0.0,
  166: 7.7,
  167: 27.6,
  168: 0.0,
  169: 0.0,
  170: 0.0,
  171: 28.6,
  172: 0.0,
  173: 50.5,
  174: 0.0,
  175: 0.0,
  176: 0.0,
  177: 0.0,
  178: 0.0,
  179: 0.0,
  180: 0.0,
  181: 0.0,
  182: 7.3,
  183: 35.4,
  184: 19.0,
  185: 0.0,
  186: 0.0,
  187: 0.0,
  188: 0.0,
  189: 74.0,
  190: 0.0,
  191: 0.8,
  192: 5.3,
  193: 0.0,
  194: 0.0,
  195: 0.0,
  196: 0.0,
  197: 3.8,
  198: 13.4,
  199: 2.8,
  200: 36.3,
  201: 0.0,
  202: 53.0,
  203: 36.9,
  204: 11.0,
  205: 0.0,
  206: 8.7,
  207: 0.0,
  208: 78.7,
  209: 0.0,
  210: 4.0,
  211: 0.0,
  212: 10.6,
  213: 0.0,
  214: 0.0,
  215: 10.7,
  216: 0.0,
  217: 0.0,
  218: 0.0,
  219: 0.0,
  220: 0.0,
  221: 45.0,
  222: 0.0,
  223: 0.0,
  224: 0.0,
  225: 0.0,
  226: 12.2,
  227: 0.0,
  228: 0.0,
  229: 0.0,
  230: 126.0,
  231: 0.0,
  232: 0.0,
  233: 0.0,
  234: 0.0,
  235: 0.0,
  236: 0.0,
  237: 0.0,
  238: 0.0,
  239: 0.0,
  240: 42.3,
  241: 0.0,
  242: 38.0,
  243: 0.0,
  244: 0.0,
  245: 0.0,
  246: 16.9,
  247: 0.0,
  248: 40.0,
  249: 6.0,
  250: 0.0,
  251: 39.5,
  252: 12.0,
  253: 0.0,
  254: 70.0,
  255: 11.0,
  256: 62.0,
  257: 0.0,
  258: 54.0,
  259: 43.0,
  260: 0.0,
  261: 0.0,
  262: 14.0,
  263: 43.3,
  264: 0.0,
  265: 33.3,
  266: 32.0,
  267: 0.0,
  268: 0.0,
  269: 0.0,
  270: 0.0,
  271: 60.0,
  272: 12.6,
  273: 0.0,
  274: 0.0,
  275: 0.0,
  276: 5.2,
  277: 0.0,
  278: 3.6,
  279: 0.0,
  280: 0.0,
  281: 0.0,
  282: 0.0,
  283: 0.0,
  284: 0.0,
  285: 0.0,
  286: 0.0,
  287: 0.0,
  288: 0.0,
  289: 0.0,
  290: 4.7,
  291: 0.0,
  292: 0.0,
  293: 0.0,
  294: 0.0,
  295: 0.0,
  296: 0.0,
  297: 0.0,
  298: 0.0,
  299: 0.0,
  300: 0.0,
  301: 0.0,
  302: 0.0,
  303: 0.0,
  304: 0.0,
  305: 0.0,
  306: 0.0,
  307: 0.0,
  308: 0.0,
  309: 0.0,
  310: 0.0,
  311: 0.0,
  312: 0.0,
  313: 0.0,
  314: 0.0,
  315: 0.0,
  316: 0.0,
  317: 0.0,
  318: 0.0,
  319: 0.0,
  320: 0.0,
  321: 0.0,
  322: 0.0,
  323: 0.0,
  324: 0.0,
  325: 0.0,
  326: 0.0,
  327: 0.0,
  328: 0.0,
  329: 0.0,
  330: 0.0,
  331: 0.0,
  332: 0.0,
  333: 0.0,
  334: 0.0,
  335: 0.0,
  336: 0.0,
  337: 0.0,
  338: 0.0,
  339: 0.0,
  340: 0.0,
  341: 0.0,
  342: 0.0,
  343: 0.0,
  344: 0.0,
  345: 0.0,
  346: 0.0,
  347: 0.0,
  348: 0.0,
  349: 0.0,
  350: 0.0,
  351: 0.0,
  352: 0.0,
  353: 0.0,
  354: 0.0,
  355: 0.0,
  356: 0.0,
  357: 0.0,
  358: 0.0,
  359: 0.0,
  360: 0.0,
  361: 0.0,
  362: 0.0,
  363: 0.0,
  364: 0.0}}
```

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(df) to load the data to try your code

Comment: "there should be rain between the 4th and the 10th day after X": at least one time or every day between 4th and 10th?

Comment: The year starts the 1st of January and ends in december

Comment: you need to put your attempt, and what parts are you struggling with... not just "here is a homework/code test/etc  question"

Comment: Yes there should be rain between the 4th and the 10th at least one time

Comment: Ok @JoranBeasley I need an iteration to find the for each year here is what I have done

Comment: `cond_1 = inter_Bafoulabe["Date"].dt.month >= 5
cond_2 = inter_Bafoulabe["Rain"].shift(-3).rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum() >= 20
cond_3 = inter_Bafoulabe["Rain"].shift(-4).rolling(6, min_periods=1).max() > 0
inter_Bafoulabe[cond_1 & cond_2 & cond_3].iloc[0]["Date"]`

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? I suppose you already know X

Comment: I want to repeat this process for each year of my dataset. I have more than 76 years and I have to find the onset for each one of those years

Comment: You have just to iterate over `for year, df in inter_Bafoulabe.groupby(inter_Bafoulabe["Date"].dt.year)`

Comment: This only repeats the same date found in the first year for the other years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that on your full data:

```
for year, df in inter_Bafoulabe.groupby(inter_Bafoulabe["Date"].dt.year):
    m1 = df['Date'].dt.month >= 5
    m2 = df['Rain'].shift(1).rolling(3).sum().shift(-4) >= 20
    m3 = df['Rain'].shift(3).rolling(7).sum().shift(-9) - df['Rain'].rolling(3).sum().shift(-2) > 0
    day = df.loc[m1 & m2 & m3, 'Date'].iloc[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if not df[m1 & m2 & m3].empty else 'Day not found'
    print(f"{year}: {day}")
```

Comment: I think `cond_2` is more like: `df.Rain.rolling(4).sum().shift(-3) - df.Rain >= 20`?

Comment: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
----> 6     rainfall_season_day.append(df[cond_1 & cond_2 & cond_3].iloc[0]["Date"])

Comment: I think neither conditions are satisfied so `.iloc[0]` raises an exception.

Comment: I do not know, why subtract by df1 and where is df1 coming from ?

Comment: df1 is a typo and "the total rain in the next 3 days after X" so the potential X day is not in the sum, isn't it?

Comment: Oh so we should use and instead of or for the 3rd condition while appending

Comment: No X is not in the sum

Comment: So you need to subtract it on the rolling: (X0 + X1 + X2 + X3) - X0

Comment: Yes, please.  (X0 + X1 + X2 + X3) - X0

Comment: Yes! I need to subtract it on the rolling: (X0 + X1 + X2 + X3) - X0 –

Comment: @IssaKASSOGUE: can you try my solution please?